# Can I steal a question from a closed site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Can I ask questions that were asked on the closed site as my own? What if I give attribution?

Comment: I was checking the old dumps some time ago, but at the first look I haven't seen some good candidates. So it's great you've found some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe so, since all user contributions are licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required (including the one from the previous dumps), so as long you give the attribution, that should be fine. In this case, it won't be stealing, but republishing.

See: [What is the license for the content I post?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/licensing)

> [Proper attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) is required if you republish any Stack Exchange content.